# Is there a way to identify the account which bought an app?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, encryption, in-app-purchase, account

I want to use In-App-Purchase to download contents to an app. To prevent the content from being "stolen", I want to give every user an encrypted download-link, which only can be decrypted on the current device. The file(s) where the encrypted links are stored should be synchronized on other devices of the same user, so using the UUID for encryption/decryption won't work.

Is there some information (account-id, hash, whatever), that my app can query on all of the users devices and that gives the same result when called on devices that bought the app with the same itunes account?

If not, what would be the appropriate way to solve the original problem? I want to prevent somebody getting the download-link from one device and using it on another device without having to pay for it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the Store Kit framework will take care of this for you.  Unless I misunderstand your question. I'm not sure how your content could be stolen if it can only be downloaded by your app after your app confirms that payment has been authorized.

From the [iOS Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH1-SW1):

> You implement In App Purchase in your
>   iOS application using the Store Kit
>   framework. Store Kit connects to the
>   App Store on your application's behalf
>   to securely process payments from the
>   user. Store Kit prompts the user to
>   authorize the payment, then notifies
>   your application so that it can
>   provide items the user purchased.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to accomplish what you are trying to do is to send the IAP receipt to the server and have it respond with the content if the receipt validates. See [Verifying Store Receipts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#Documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html).